# function that returns the number of nodes in a certain level of a binary search tree

Tags: c++

I have to create a function `getNodesatLevel` that returns the number of nodes at a level, however, I'm getting a "may reach end of void function" error. This is for a Binary Search tree, and I'm required to use recursion for this function.

```
int TreeType::getNodesAtLevel(TreeNode * &node, int level, ItemType * mainArr)
{
    int currentLevel = 0;
    int NodeCount = 1;

    if(currentLevel == level)
    {
        NodeCount++;
        return NodeCount;
    }
    else if(currentLevel != level)
    {
        currentLevel++;

        if(node->left != NULL)
            getNodesAtLevel(node->left, level, mainArr);

        if(node->right != NULL)
            getNodesAtLevel(node->right, level, mainArr);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a lot of how recursive functions work. `currentLevel` and `NodeCount` do not persist inside the new scope when you call the function again. You also don't return the value of your recursive calls. Specific to the error code, not all paths in your function return a value.

Answer (score 5):

The error is basically what it says on the tin: your function can reach the end without returning a value.

To see why, let's just look at your outer if statement:

```
if(node->left != NULL)
    //...
if(node->right != NULL)
    //...
//...
```

What happens if both `node->left` *and* `node->right` are null? You don't handle this case at all. That's a bug.

Secondly (and arguably most importantly) you call yourself recursively, but don't do anything with the return value of your function. You don't return it, and you don't save it for later either. That means nothing really happens to it. It just gets lost.

Because of this, your function won't return this value at all. That creates situations in which **nothing** is returned.

So, to fix this, figure out what you want to do with the recursive return value of your function and either a) save it in a temporary variable, or b) simply return it. Which one you choose will depend on what you want your function to count.

Also, make sure you return a value even if both sides of the tree are NULL.